# Trouble with sqlalchemy join query - get the next date from child

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using the example below, i'm trying to make a single query that will get my list of offices, and pull the next upcoming visit from the child table.

```
class Office(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    office_name = db.Column(db.String(100))

    visits = db.relationship('Visit', backref='office', lazy='select', order_by='desc(Visit.visit_date)')

class Visit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    visit_date = db.Column(db.Date)

    office_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('office.id'))
```

I've been able to create a query in raw SQL that will return what i need:

```
SELECT * FROM office 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT office_id, visit_date FROM visit WHERE visit_date >= date('now') 
GROUP BY office_id ) 
AS next_vis ON id = next_vis.office_id
```

But i haven't been able to convert the above in SQLAlchemy.

Closest i've got to is this:

```
next_vis = db.session.query(Visit.office_id, Visit.visit_date).filter(
        Visit.visit_date >= datetime.utcnow().date()).order_by(
            Visit.visit_date.asc()).group_by(Visit.office_id).subquery()

offices = db.session.query(Office, next_vis.c.visit_date).outerjoin(
    next_vis, Office.id == next_vis.c.office_id).order_by(
        Office.office_name.asc())
```

But the only problem is it returns a tuple of (office, date) but ideally i want it returned as a single object. Is that not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested i went about this a slightly different way.

I switched from a join query to adding a column property in my Office model:

```
class Office(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    office_name = db.Column(db.String(100))

    visits = db.relationship('Visit', backref='office', lazy='select', 
                order_by='desc(Visit.visit_date)')

    next_vis = column_property(
        select([Visit.visit_date]).where(
            and_(Visit.office_id == id, Visit.visit_date >= db.func.current_date())).order_by(
                Visit.visit_date.asc()).correlate_except(Visit))
```

Now when i do Office.query.all() i can do:

```
for i in Office.query.all():
    print(i.next_vis)
```

If i've overlooked anything please let me know!

Thanks,